# How to center alignment of some table entries with predefined widths?

Tags: tables, formatting, multirow, multicolumn, arrays

In the table below, the methodologies cell and all numeral entries of quantile columns (Qs) are aligned to the right, while they should be centered horizontally and vertically.
By the way, when I changed (just for test) the width of (Q=50) column, the entries for that column are centered and look good!!
How can I center the entries of Methodologies cell and the numeral entries of quartiles columns with the predefined widths (1.5cm to first column and 0.5cm to numeral cells) in below table?
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Illustrative Table}
\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
\begin{tabular} 
{|M{1.5cm}|M{0.5cm}|M{0.5cm}|M{0.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{0.5cm}|M{0.5cm}|
M{0.5cm}|M{0.5cm}|M{0.5cm}|M{0.75cm}|M{0.75cm}|M{0.75cm}|M{0.75cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{4}{1.5cm}{\centering{Methodologies}}& \multicolumn{9}   
{c|}{\multirow{2}{4.5cm}{RR Quantiles (1 to 99)}}
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Probability of RR Classes} \\
\cline{11-14} & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{}& Class1    & Class2    & Class3   &   Class4  \\ 
\cline{2-14}  & Q1  & Q45  & Q46  & Q50   & Q61 & Q62   & Q80   & Q81   & Q99   & (Up, HR)  & (Up, LR)  & (Down, HR)  & (Down, LR) \\ \hline
A & 0.101 & 0.261 & 0.265 & 0.279 & 0.318 & 0.321 & 0.396 & 0.401 & 0.457 & 20\% & 80\% & 0\% & 0\% \\ \hline
B & 0.266 & 0.364 & 0.366 & 0.374 & 0.398 & 0.400 & 0.445 & 0.449 & 0.483 & 39\% & 61\% & 0\% & 0\%  \\ \hline
C & 0.313 & 0.399 & 0.401 & 0.409 & 0.430 & 0.432 & 0.472 & 0.475 & 0.505 & 55\% & 45\% & 0\% & 0\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your cells are to narrow for contents in it, so it is pushed right. try `\begin{tabular}{|c|*{9}{M{0.6cm}|}*{4}{M{0.75cm}|}}`. however in your document is sufficient space to make table even wider. and use slightly larger font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not clear why you use so narrow cells when there is sufficient space to use their natural width for all cells which has one line content. now, consequently to fixed width, which is smaller than natural width of content (which can not be broken into two lines) are pushed to right border.

try the following and see if it is acceptable to you (readers will be thankful for larger font size):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Illustrative Table}
\small%\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{9}{c|}*{4}{M{1cm}|}}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\centering{Methodologies}}& \multicolumn{9}
{c|}{\multirow{2}{4.5cm}{RR Quantiles (1 to 99)}}
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Probability of RR Classes} \\
\cline{11-14} & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{}& Class1    & Class2    & Class3   &   Class4  \\
\cline{2-14}  & Q1  & Q45  & Q46  & Q50   & Q61 & Q62   & Q80   & Q81   & Q99   & (Up, HR)  & (Up, LR)  & (Down, HR)  & (Down, LR) \\ \hline
A & 0.101 & 0.261 & 0.265 & 0.279 & 0.318 & 0.321 & 0.396 & 0.401 & 0.457 & 20\% & 80\% & 0\% & 0\% \\ \hline
B & 0.266 & 0.364 & 0.366 & 0.374 & 0.398 & 0.400 & 0.445 & 0.449 & 0.483 & 39\% & 61\% & 0\% & 0\%  \\ \hline
C & 0.313 & 0.399 & 0.401 & 0.409 & 0.430 & 0.432 & 0.472 & 0.475 & 0.505 & 55\% & 45\% & 0\% & 0\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: Thanks Zarko for your response and your touches to the code.